# Add custom button color to Visual Composer button settings

Tags: wordpress, visual-composer

Is there a way to add a custom color/value to the color drop down of the button settings in visual composer? The site I'm developing has lots of colored buttons and rather than overriding one of the existing button classes with css I'd rather add the color(s) to the drop down. Otherwise I have to explain to the client "when you want this color button you have to select x color from the drop down". Which is just confusing.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this:

https://kb.wpbakery.com/docs/developers-how-tos/update-single-param-values/

Change all "cta_button" occurrences to "btn". Save the page with the button you want and the color you just created, then use Chrome to inspect the created element. It will come with a class named something like 'vc_btn_color-yourcolor'.

Just style that color on your style.css later.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give this a try.

Comment: Any questions leave a comment and I'll try to help :)

Comment: I cannot enter https://wpbakery.atlassian.net/wiki/display/VC/Update+Single+Param+Values - is there a free-to-access link?

Comment: Apparently they changed the URL, will update my answer. URL now here: https://kb.wpbakery.com/docs/developers-how-tos/update-single-param-values/

Comment: It is obnoxious that such a simple thing has to be so difficult. VC needs to let you dynamically define colors somewhere in the UI and then load them in this box.